# How to connect a fiber to a laser module

Tags: laser-diode

I need to connect a fiber to a laser module, to make a fiber coupled laser module.

If the wavelength of the laser is 532nm , what is the type of the fiber ?
How can I connect the fiber to the laser module ?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Choice of fiber will depend on the specs of the laser (single vs multimode, power).  Once you have the fiber, you would focus the laser beam down into the fiber core using a lens.   Post the specs for your laser.

Comment: 532 nm is green. Do you want plastic or glass? How can we tell what module you have or need?

Comment: A green laser is unusual to be fiber coupled. I guess it's not for communication then. If your module is not equipped with a connector fixture good luck, you'll have to improvise a precision mechanical coupling

Comment: It’s not easy being green......

Comment: Fiber coupling a laser is not that hard, especially for multimode (single mode is a little harder but not impossible).  You can buy equipment to do it, but it does require a little bit of thought and effort.